# primeNG upgrading to 8.0.1 error loading DataTable

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to upgrade my primeng package from 7 to 8.

I am getting the following error:

**anager-console/src/main/frontend/node_modules/primeng/primeng"' has no exported member 'DataTable'**

the following import is not found in the component file

```
import { DataTable } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

**package.json**

```
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.15",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "floatthead": "^2.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "ng-treetable": "^1.3.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.15",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.14.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  }
```

**Update**

I did update the Angular to 8 and still have the same issue.

After further investigation, the DataTable component was removed in primeNG 8.
I looked at release notes, and there is nothing mention about the removing DataTable component. Now I need to find out what do I use instead..

[link to primeNg issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7951)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

replaced all `import { DataTable } from 'primeng/primeng';`
with import `{ Table } from 'primeng/table';`
solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

datatable is deprecated in favor of turbotable:

```
TurboTable
Table is the successor of p-dataTable with a lightning fast performance (at least 10x faster) and excellent level of control over the presentation. p-table is called as TurboTable in order to differantiate if from the deprecated p-dataTable.
```

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-7.1.3/#/table

Im linking to version 7 since 8 doesn't even show the deprecation message anymore.

Comment: I am not using the p-dataTable... I use p-table

Answer (score 0):

Angular 8 DataTable disappeared:

```
import { TableModule } from "primeng/table";
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Angular 8** DataTable is being removed...it seems.
So, if your project has a import like this ;

```
 **import { DataTable } from 'primeng/primeng';
    
   @ViewChild('dt') dataTable: DataTable;**
```

then change it to ,

```
**import { Table } from 'primeng/table';

@ViewChild('dt', {static: true}) dataTable: Table;**
```

Also , remove and replace/import DataTableModule with TableModule